# troubles with dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, windows

i am running Windows 10 and am trying to dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04.  I have followed everything correctly i made a boot-able USB and shrunk my partition and done everything else.  I can load into Ubuntu and install it but after installing it and restarting i cant load back into the account i made and have to go through the whole installation process again.

Comment: You are not making sense or you aren't removing the installation media before restarting.

Comment: Did you removed the USB after installation is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the modern machines come with UEFI replacing the BIOS integration to initiate boot an add some extra features ([Check on wiki-page for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)) , Ubuntu or any other linux explicitly requires a primary partition to boot.

Having a Windows10 already installed would be having UEFI enabled obviously. In such case if you install Ubuntu and MBR is selected as Harddisk's first location, that won't help to get your linux to boot.

A workaround is to totally disable the UEFI support and enable the Legacy support only from BIOS. After you need to install Windows & Ubuntu again so that they just use MBR, same like old school method. In this way you'll have Ubuntu's GRUB sitting on top and will provide a menu to switch to installed OSs.

Comment: If i reinstall windows wouldn't i lose everything on it?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Can't do much about that. Anyways disabling the UEFI should be done at very first place before installing any OS.